# Css: min-height interpreted as height (iPhone webapp)

Tags: html, css, iphone-web-app

I building an *iPhone webb app based on iWebKit's framework*. I'm currently integrating a CSS div slider to improve the navigation between pages (divs) and everything works fine except one thing.

It appears as if I'm supposed to set a fixed height value to the div containing the sliding objects. These objects will contain quite a lot of content and wary in size, hence the divs/page have to expand vertically by default. For some reason, **it appears as if the browser interprets min-height as height and doesn't expand the div to display all content.** I realize there's probably a small mistake somewhere, something I have forgotten to add or remove. Please help me by pointing these out for me. Thanks

Wrapper containing the slides:

```
#contentWrapper {
float: left;
min-height:305px;
position: relative;
margin:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
display:block !important;
}
```

Class added on every sliding obj

```
.additional-block {
height:auto;
position: absolute;
padding-bottom:30px;
display:block !important;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://utvecklingspunkten.se/heightIssue.php
Click on "Click" to see the actual issue appearing; the text is cut off below 305 px. The issue appears in all browsers including Safari for iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `overflow: hidden` on your "content2" div that's conflicting here. Setting that means that the container can overflow, so it does. (Removing the min-height will show you that it would be 0 pixels high otherwise.)

Removing the overflow setting will have the effect I think you want.

Comment: Thanks @Johno for your quick response. However, that won't quite do it. Removing overflow:hidden means the page will display veritical and horizontal scrollbars. If i set overflow-x: to hidden. A veritical scrollbar will appear in the top right corner which underlines that the fact that this is not solving the actual issue but merely improving it.